# errors in socket communication using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a socket with client server communication using python and I want through my client send a latitude, longitude, an hour and a date to get a pressure and a temperature that is in my grib file but my client script gives me this error

> Client "JSON_OBJECT = response.loads (response.read ())
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loads'

On my server appears to me that the errors are at this location

```
"Conn.send (get_pressure_and_temperature (request_string))"
"JSON_OBJECT = json.loads (request_string)"
```

This is my code of the client

```
import socket
import os
import sys
import json


timestamp   = 20160210  
hour        = 6
latitude    = 20
longitude   = 20

HOST = ''    # The remote host
PORT = 10000              # The same port as used by the server

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
#latitude = raw_input ("latitude: \t" )
#longitude = raw_input ("longitude: \t" )
#s.send(latitude)
#s.send(longitude)
#s.send(string)
string = {"timestamp": timestamp, "hour": hour, "lat": latitude, "long": longitude}
s.send(json.dumps(string))
response = s.recv(1024)
json_object = response.loads(response)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(json_object)
```

And of the server is :

Necessary imports

```
import math
import numpy
import pygrib
import sys
import time
import pressure_temperature
import aux
import socket
import os
import json

args=sys.argv               # List of arguments of the comand line

def get_pressure_and_temperature(request_string):
    json_object = json.loads(request_string)
    print json_object
    timestamp = int(json_object["timestamp"])
    print timestamp
    hour = float(json_object["hour"])
    print hour
    latitude = float(json_object["lat"])
    print latitude
    longitude = float(json_object["long"])
    print longitude
    pressure_temperature_result = pressure_temperature.build_data(timestamp, hour, latitude, longitude)
    print "result = ", pressure_temperature_result
    return json.dumps(pressure_temperature_result) 

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 10000              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, cliente = s.accept()
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        s.close()
        print 'Connected by', cliente
        while True:
                        request_string = conn.recv(1024)
            conn.send(get_pressure_and_temperature(request_string))
            if not request_string: break
            print "ok"
        print "Finalizando conexao com cliente", cliente
        #conn.close()
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        conn.close()
```

Comment: I think you mean `json.loads(response)` [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load)

Comment: where sorry, can you indicate-me please  ?

Comment: I saw it, thanks men xp

Comment: here `json_object = response.loads(response)` it should be `json_object = json.loads(respnse)`. Because `response` is string (or bytes) and you want to use `json` module to turn it into a json object with function [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load)